# React native statusbar not working with react-navigation in android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, native-base, android-statusbar

Versions:

```
   "native-base": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.2",
    "react-native-global-font": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.11"
```

When i add react-navigation i am not able to change statusbar color, my statusbar become blue.

Here's my Navigationview.js code

```
    render() {
          return (
            <Root style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar
                  backgroundColor="white"
                  barStyle="dark-content"
                />
                <MainView />
            </Root>
          );
        }

    const drawerHeader = (props) => (
  <Container style={styles.container}>
    <Header style={styles.header}>
      <Body style={styles.body}>
        <Icon name="person" style={{ fontSize: 40, color: '#CCCCCC' }} />
      </Body>
    </Header>
    <Content>
    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
        <DrawerItems {...props} />
        <Button title="Logout" onPress={() => Actions.reset('login')} />
    </SafeAreaView>
    </Content>
  </Container>
);

    const MainView = DrawerNavigator({
      DASHBOARD: {
        screen: Dashboard,
      },
      LOGOUT: {
        screen: LoginForm,
      }
    }, {
        initialRouteName: 'DASHBOARD',
        contentComponent: drawerHeader,
        drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
        drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
        drawerToogleRoute: 'DrawerToogle'
    });

i even set statusbar color in Dashboard screen, still not change.

Dashboard.js

    <Container>
            <Header androidStatusBarColor="#FFF" style={{backgroundColor:'#000'}}>
              <StatusBar
                  backgroundColor="white"
                  barStyle="dark-content"
                />
              <Body>
                <Title style={{color:'#FFF'}}>My App</Title>
              </Body>
            </Header>
            <Content>
              //content of your app goes here
            </Content>
          </Container>
I m also using native-base, so i add this code in my App.js file

    render() {
        return (
          <Root style={styles.container}>
              <StatusBar
                backgroundColor="white"
                barStyle="dark-content"
              />
              {this.spinerRender()}
          </Root>
        );
      }
```

and this is working for my login and signin screen, but not with my navigationview screen.

Login and signin screen statusbar

[image]

Navigation screen statusbar

[image]

Comment: Do you use expo?

Comment: @aLIEz no i m not using expo.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a view and adding some height  in the root container as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804764/react-native-ios-statusbar-invisible-after-build/49805094#49805094)

Comment: ParentWrapper from where its derived ?

Comment: did u get solution for this ? Im facing same issue

Comment: @NabeelK yes, the problem is native-base component.. i change contentComponent view. and problem solved.

Comment: @SagarChavada Could you expand your solution?

Comment: @PhanSinh do not use native-base component in contentComponent.. thats it.

Comment: @SagarChavada My layout base:
```<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
                <View style={styles.container}>

                    <StatusBar
                       backgroundColor={'red'}
                        barStyle={'dark-content'}
                       translucent={false}
                  />
             ....
</SafeAreaView>```

In content component i don't use container component.

Comment: @SagarChavada I see that my issue only in android version < 21. I test on android 26, it's working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It Fixed Now.

Problem, is native-base component so I change contentComponent view to this.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}> 
<View style={styles.container}> 
   <StatusBar backgroundColor={'red'} barStyle={'dark-content'} translucent={false} /> 
.... 
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 4):

My issue was slightly different.

The previous screen that I navigated from had set `StatusBar` hidden to true.

```
// previous screen that I navigated from
<StatusBar hidden animated />
```

So I had to explicitly change `StatusBar` hidden to `false` and `animated` to `true` on the new screen:

```
// new screen needs hidden={false} to show up
<StatusBar hidden={false} animated />
```

Answer (score 1):

For any one using native-base Header and having this problem, you could use the prop iosBarStyle like the following

```
    <Header
      iosBarStyle="dark-content"
```

Answer (score 0):

For any one using native-base `Header` and having this problem, you could use the prop `androidStatusBarColor` like the following

```
<Header style={styles.header} androidStatusBarColor="#f8bb12">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this to exclude the notch if present.

```
import React from "react";
import {Text, SafeAreaView, StatusBar} from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <StatusBar hidden />
      <SafeAreaView> 
        <Text>Your Code</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

by using StatusBar with hidden can exclude the top notch.

Answer (score 0):

*statusbar color in react native app*

```
<View>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor="red"></StatusBar>

     <Text>
           hii
     <Text>

</View>
```